# The administrator menu disappeared

Tags: commerce, security, .htaccess

I added the following code in my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
  Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
  Header always set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
  Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com"
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</IfModule>
```

and the Administrator menu drupal no longer appear on my site. When I delete this line, the menu reappears. How to solve this problem ?

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you inspect with Dev tool to see if the administrator menu exists in source?

Comment: @Jimmy Ko I've updated the question and the menu bar disappears from the source

Comment: Can you add `dpm()` before `$page['page_bottom']['admin_menu']['#markup'] = admin_menu_output($complete);` in admin_menu.module? I suspect the condition `!$complete && !empty($_COOKIE['has_js']) && ($hash = admin_menu_cache_get($cid))` is failed. The most probably problem is the `has_js` value.

Comment: @Jimmy Ko I can not do that. I'm not a programmer.
Should I change the line Content-Security-Policy?

Comment: I can't find problem from your policy, but I suspect if the JS cannot be loaded. Can you see any JS loaded from admin_menu?

Comment: Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"

Comment: @Jimmy Ko I can not, so I replaced the code above

Comment: I don't understand. So is the Content-Security-Policy is showing what you have set?

Answer (score 0):

Check with the styles/css hiding the administrator menu.
style-src is script-src’s counterpart for stylesheets.

Comment: I do not understand, what should I write in my file?

Comment: You inspect the webpage to see wheteher the administrator menu exist in the  page source, also check the visibility of the toolbar menu,if the visiibilty is false or have feature display:none ,then administrator menu will be hidden from the webpage.

Comment: I've updated the question and the menu bar disappears from the source